# Change date format for a column openpyxl

Tags: python, datetime, openpyxl

In column U is a list of dates in the format of `2020-01-21 09:50:10.959355-05:00`. I am trying to convert all of U into `mm/dd/yy` format. I am getting the error of `ValueError: Style Normal exists already`. I have also been looking into just separating the cells by the space between the `yy hh`. Which ever answer is simplest. Here is my code. Please help

```py
date_style = NamedStyle(number_format='dd/mm/yy')
for row in sheet1.iter_rows(min_col=21, max_col=21):
    for cell in row:
        cell.style = date_style
```

Comment: I updated my answer below, you'll get the `mm/dd/yy` format you requested originally.

Comment: You should always include the full traceback of any error, but basically you need to gvie your style a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proper way to use the styling, as you had requested:

```py
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle
date_style = NamedStyle(name='date_style',number_format='dd/mm/yy')
wb.add_named_style(date_style)
for row in ws8.iter_rows(min_col=21, max_col=21):
    for cell in row:
        cell.style = date_style
```

Splitting on the space is another way to do this:

```py
import datetime
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col=21, max_col=21):
    for cell in row:
        cell.value = datetime.datetime.strptime(cell.value.split()[0], '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%m/%d/%y')
```

The cell's value will be split on the white space into two values, one being at index 0, the other being at index 1. You want to date part, so you'll select `[0]`. Then using the `datetime` library, you can reformat the date as you wish.

Input:

```
2020-01-21 09:50:10.959355-05:00
```

Output:

```
01/21/20
```

Comment: This is not the same as assigning a style.

Comment: You are right, I updated my code. Thanks again @CharlieClark